# asp.net mvc 3 razor deploy IIS7

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, deployment

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [asp.net mvc 3 web application does not working after deploy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10674021/asp-net-mvc-3-web-application-does-not-working-after-deploy)

I have deployed asp.net mvc 3 razor on iis 7 but it's not working

Works only that view which does not need database connection.

I am sure that i have inputed correct connection string in web.config file.

Is there any other connection string to change?

Older asp.net web pages site working good with same connection string

Comment: Sorry, an error occurred while processing your request. this is error message but as i said views working perfectly which does not need database

Answer (score 0):

Set [customerrors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h0hfz6fc.aspx) to `off`, that will give you a more detailed error that you use to debug.

You can find more ASP.NET debugging suggestions in the [AppHarbor FAQ](http://support.appharbor.com/kb/getting-started/frequently-asked-questions).