# asp.net mvc 3 web application does not working after deploy

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, sql-server-2008, razor

I have deplyoed asp.net mvc 3 razor view engine application on IIS 7. Server using windows server 2008 with sql server 2008. There is installed asp.net mvc 3

I have clicked publish button in Visual Studio 2010. Published it on local folder and then copied in server.

I am getting error > `Sorry, an error occurred while processing your request.`

This error shows only that views which does needs sql connection so other pages loading perfectly.

I am sure that i have changed connection string with correct connection string.

Please help me there is not anything helpful in web.

Thanks

Comment: Can you open the page on the web-server? So you get a specific error. You should also check the config in web.config for error-pages. (Remote only, Off, On)

Comment: Do you use 'trusted connection' or did you put the credentials in the connection string?

Comment: Also you could check the server's event log looking for the exception

Comment: Yes i can. In internet explorer im getting The website cannot display the page. and in fire fox im getting same error as in remote computer

Comment: yes i am using trusted connection

Comment: @Acid If you're using the trusted connection, then you should check if your app is able to log on to SQL Server (probably not). Usually it logs on as IIS APPPOOL\Default or IIS APPOOL\YourAppName, depending what app pool you specified. That just won't fly with SQL Server right away. Either way, you can map the `NetworkService` in SQL Server to be able to read/write to the database, and then change the app pool's identity to `NetworkService`. Or you can try to add the app pool as an SQL Server login - I don't know if it's possible though, I haven't tried it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you have to know what is the exception that is causing the error view to show up.

I can suggest you three options.

1. Turn off the `<customErrors`> section, so the `HandleError` filter won't work and you can see the *real exception*.
2. The `HandleError` filter also passes a `HandleErrorInfo` instance to the error view, so you can display the complete exception in the error view itself *(just to know the error not a wise idea in production)* by accessing that model.

   ```
   @model System.Web.Mvc.HandleErrorInfo

   <p>
      The exception is: @Model.Exception
   </p>
   ```
3. You can try **ELMAH** library that records all the un-handled exceptions. The `HandleError` filter suppresses the exception and stops them logged by **ELMAH**, so you should better switch off the `HandleError` when you are trying **ELMAH**. You have to configure the `ELMAH` in a separate database and it provides a page that lists all the recent errors.

Answer (score 0):

Check the following:

- The app pool you're deploying it to in IIS is using the correct version of .NET (should be using a .NET 4 Integrated Mode App Pool)
- If it's an error that's preventing anything from running in ASP.NET, then errors should be being logged to the Event Log on the server.  Check the Application and/or System log.

Comment: Thank you for replay app pool is configured correctly i have errors in Event viewer :Login failed for user 'IIS APPPOOL\NGG'. Reason: Failed to open the explicitly specified database. [CLIENT: <local machine>]

Comment: That sounds like permissions on your database then.  Either file permissions if it's something like SqlCe, or specify a username and password in the connection string if it's SQL Server/Express.

Comment: Please advice me something. I dont know how to do. How i can google my problem?

Comment: You'll need to supply some more details, such as what database engine you're using, what your connection string looks like etc.

Comment: @Acid, does that use "IIS APPPOOL\NGG" have permission to access the database?

Comment: no it does not. I have added new database users 'IIS APPPOOL\NGG' then tried to added this user to my database owner and its shows such error: owner failed for database NGG(Microsoft.sqlserver.smo)

Comment: You won't be able to add a user for IIS APPPOOL\NCG.  Create an SQL login that does have permission to access the database, and specify this user + password in your connection string.

Answer (score 0):

There is some error in some code of that requested page. So ASP.NET MVC is showing the content of error.cshtml.

You can disable custom error page in your web.config so that you can see the error in the browser. Keep in mind that not only you, everyone can see that. So you better change that settings back once you figure out what is the problem. You can also set the value to `remoteonly` so that that only it will be visible from the server. This works only if you have remote access to the server.